# Display a status popup when a button is clicked and redirect to the parent window - SpringBoot

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have created a `Spring Boot` application and it displays the following table on the browser when I hit `localhost:8080/displayResults`

```
╔═════╦══════╦════════════════════╗
║ ID  ║ Name ║       Action       ║
╠═════╬══════╬════════════════════╣
║ 001 ║ one  ║ start|stop|restart ║
║ 002 ║ two  ║ start|stop|restart ║
╚═════╩══════╩════════════════════╝
```

I have a controller as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "displayResults", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getResults(ModelMap model) {
    List<Bean> beanToDisplay = handler.getData();
    return new ModelAndView("Results", "beanToDisplay", beanToDisplay);
}
```

The above controller is the one that displays the aforementioned table.

Now my requirement is when I click on the `start` button or `stop` button or `restart` button it should call another method called `handler.stop()` etc. This method checks the existing status of the server and starts or stops accordingly. It takes sometime (may be like 10 seconds) for this method to return a status. 
Until then it should display a popup as soon as the "start or stop or restart" button is clicked and then redirect back to the same parent page. Additionally I also need to pass the `ID` to the controller along with the `start` click

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("alert here");
```

is a simple js way of making a pop up box appear

for the rest i would do something like

```
function myFunction() {
var button //define the button here

 if (button === "GetKeyDown") 
  {
   window.location='http://www.website.com';
   alert("alert here");               
  }
}
```

this is the best i can think of as i haven't done much with js in a while

Comment: I'm not really worried about JS. I'd like to get a solution for the `controller` setup and calling the method to start and stop